# Trap Error on Duplicate Record Creation

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007, vba

First, thank you for helping me. Second, I'm pretty sure the answer to my question is out there but I can't seem to find it. Here's what I'm trying to do.

I have a form that is based on the table Tbl_LedgerEntry. It lists an ID#, Date, Status of Job, and details. There is a second table Tbl_LedgerAccouting that lists related accounting transactions (TransID, Check #, Check Amount, Debit/Credit) based on the Tbl_LedgerEntry ID#. There can only be one entry in the Tbl_LedgerAccounting for any one ID#. The separate tables exist because there are several ID# where there is no corresponding TransID.

I have created a button that adds a record to the Tbl_LedgerAccounting. However, if there is already a TransID for the corresponding ID# then it errors on me AFTER the user inputs the accounting information. I want it to error BEFORE the user inputs the information. Basically, I need my VBA to check to see if a record in Tbl_LedgerAccounting already exists for the related ID# prior to asking the user for input.

Table Formats

Tbl_LedgerEntry

ID#(AutoNumber & Key), JobID, Date, Status, Details

Tbl_LedgerAccounting

TransID=ID# from Tbl_LedgerEntry (also Key in this table), Check Amount, Check Number, Debit/Credit

Long story short, I need to lookup the TransID and see if it exists in the Tbl_LedgerAccounting prior to input requests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I can see this happening is that you can check if a record exists when you're performing the Form_Load event.  That is, assuming tbl_LedgerAccounting is being interfaced through its own form.  Not via a subform, mind you, but its own stand-alone form.  If so, you could add something like this to the Load event:

```
Dim db as Database
Dim rec as Recordset

Set db = CurrentDB
'I'm assuming you're entering the TransID into a textbox in a prior form (aka OtherFormName)
Set rec = db.OpenRecordset ("Select TransID from Tbl_LedgerAccounting WHERE TransID = " & Forms!OtherFormName.TransID & "")

'If the recordset you return has more than one record...
If rec.EOF = False Then
  'TransID is in the table already, so tell the user and then close the form
  MsgBox "This TransID already exists"
  Me.Close
End If
```

You may need to tweak that a bit, but that's more or less how to do it.

Comment: Thank you so much. I did need to tweak it a bit but you provided the foundation for me to get it done.